# DateTime from view to control to Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i'm trying to pass A DateTime data type to a controller that will call a Mapper to pass it into a db. Additionally the DateTime is taken from a db at first.

**db > DateTime > View > Controller > Mapper > DB**

The Mapper is suppose to put the data into the DB the issue is that all other data goes in properly except the DateTime.

I'm Using ASP.NET core 5 and SQL server

**Model**

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Housekeeping
{
    [Key]
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string serviceName { get; set; }
    public float serviceCost { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller code**

```cs
public class HousekeepingController : Controller
{
    // private readonly Data.DataMappers.HouseKeepingTablesMapper mapper2;
    private readonly DAL.HouseKeepingMapper mapper;
    private readonly HouseKeepingTableGateway TheHouseKeepingTableGateWay;
    private readonly HouseKeepingGateway TheHouseKeepingGateWay;
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Housekeeping entity)
    {
        mapper.Insert(entity);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Request");
    }
}
```

**Mapping Class**

```cs
public class HouseKeepingMapper : IMapper<Housekeeping>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _db;
    public HouseKeepingMapper(ApplicationDBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public void Insert(Housekeeping entity)
    {
        var HousekeepingData = new GuestRequestTable();
        HousekeepingData.ServiceName = entity.serviceName;
        HousekeepingData.DateTime = entity.time;
        HousekeepingData.Status = "Pending";

        _db.GuestRequests.Add(HousekeepingData);
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Specifically this line is what passes the DateTime to the controller.
The full code is bellow the code directly below.

```html
<input type="submit"  asp-controller="Housekeeping" asp-action="Create" asp-route-serviceName="@item.serviceName" asp-route-time="@item.time" value="Confirm Booking"/>
```

```cs
@model IEnumerable<ProjectConciergeM3.Models.HousekeepingTable>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Housekeeping Request Page";
   IEnumerable<Housekeeping> bookingHousekeeping = ViewData["BookingHousekeeping"] as IEnumerable<Housekeeping>;
   IEnumerable<HousekeepingTable> HouseKeepingList = ViewData["TheHouseKeepingList"] as IEnumerable<HousekeepingTable>;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach(Housekeeping item in bookingHousekeeping)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>@item.serviceName</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>$@item.serviceCost.00</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>@item.time</b>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <form method="post">
                        <input asp-controller="Housekeeping" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.itemID" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
                </form>
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="submit"  asp-controller="Housekeeping" asp-action="Create" asp-route-serviceName="@item.serviceName" asp-route-time="@item.time" value="Confirm Booking"/>
                </form>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'doesn't go in properly', i.e. is there an error, is it malformed, is it empty?  Try adding breakpoints along the points of the process and see when the value goes awry.

Comment: i mean in the DB it show 01/01/0001 12.00.00

Comment: Hi @OhOh, do you check if you submit the button and pass the correct datetime?

Comment: @OhOh put a breakpoint in the code before you write to the database and check what you have in your time property.  I'm pretty sure you'll find it's empty.  Then work up the call chain and see where it's getting lost

Comment: i did those and i am referencing the right DateTime but all other data is recieve like name, status and etc.. but only the DateTime does not go in right

Comment: Hi @OhOh, So you mean the datetime display in html successfully but does not pass to the backend? If so, could you please share your datetime format?